# ggplot2 caching or plotting in the background

Tags: r, caching, plot, ggplot2, shiny

I'm working on a R Shiny app that plots (with `ggplot2`) information about different chromosomes, and there is also an option to show all the chromosomes together.
I have a really bad performance problem, especially with the 'all' view, I looked for some caching solutions, but didn't really find anything helpful.
I thought to put 2 tabs in my app, the first is for the single chromosomes, and the second for all together, so it would run in the background, and load while the user is still in the first tab, but when I read about `Tabsets` I found out this-

> Notice that outputs that are not visible are not re-evaluated until they become visible.

So my question is, is there a way to bypass this? or is there a way to cache a plot so when I want to plot it the only thing left to do is to draw it, and skip the construct, build, and render stages. (there is a good chance that I don't really understand the plotting process, and it's not possible)

One last thing, I am aware of (the much faster) `ggvis` and `ggobi`, but these are for now not an option.